# How to locate a commit of a submodule in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

How do you locate in GitHub a specific commit of a submodule from code that was cloned but is no longer in GitHub?

For example, I have a project that uses submodule A that in turns uses submodules B and C. I have all the source in my hard drive. Using this source, I just need to locate in GitHub a specific commit for the submodules, somehow.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If your project on your disk is still a git repo, and the A folder is also a git repo (decalred as a submodule), then its current index would have the trace of the SHA1 used for `B` and `C`.

To see that "gitlink" ([special index entry,  mode 160000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)), do a:

```
 cd A
 git ls-tree HEAD B
 160000 commit <SHA1-used-by-B> B
```